# CentOS php pecl PDO_DBLIB

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have tried to install PDO_DBLIB in CentOS 5.8, so I run follow command

```
pecl install PDO_DBLIB
```

and I get the follow message

```
pear/PDO_DBLIB requires PHP extension 'pdo' version >=1.0
```

But in http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-dblib.php, it says that is an EXPERIMENTAL pdo, so do you know another PDO that I can use to conect with sql server in CentOS 5

Thanks to every one!

Comment: have you completed this?

Answer (score 4):

See [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57045) on php.net.  One of the comments includes steps to get around this particular problem.  Basically the work around is to download the package, modifying the package.xml to remove the dependency, and then attempt to install the package locally

```
$ pecl download pdo_dblib
$ tar -xzvf PDO_DBLIB-*.tgz

Remove from package.xml and save:
<dep type="ext" rel="ge" version="1.0">pdo</dep>

$ mv package.xml ./PDO_DBLIB-X.X
$ cd PDO_DBLIB-X.X
$ pecl install package.xml
```

Or, you can just tell PECL to skip dependencies...

```
$ pecl install -n pdo_dblib
```